# Having issues getting firebase data through Oauth pin-auth session for Nest

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, firebase, nest-api

Base script:

```
from sanction import Client
# client_id & client_secret are omitted but are valid

client_pin = input('Enter PIN:')

access_token_url = 'https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token'

c = Client(
    token_endpoint=access_token_url,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret)

c.request_token(code = client_pin)
```

[[See edits for history]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26105065/revisions)

Running `c.request('/devices')` returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\nest_testing_sanction.py", line 36, in <module>
    c.request("/devices")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sanction-0.4.1-py3.4.egg\sanction\__init__.py", line 169, in request
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sanction-0.4.1-py3.4.egg\sanction\__init__.py", line 211, in transport_query
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 284, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 313, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'None/devices?access_token=c.[some long session token]'
```

Given the output it seems like I need to be putting in a generic URL so I tried `c.request('wss://developer-api.nest.com')`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\nest_testing_sanction.py", line 36, in <module>
    data = c.request(query_url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sanction-0.4.1-py3.4.egg\sanction\__init__.py", line 171, in request
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 455, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 478, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1257, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: nonewss>
```

I also tried `https` as per:

[image] - same result

By contrast, this works (for a firebase.io virtual device):

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://nesttest.firebaseio.com', None)
thermostat_result       = firebase.get('/devices', 'thermostats')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a comment, but the system does not let me comment just yet.

To your question about where to put the web pin simply add code = pin to the request_token call.

```
c.request_token(code = nest_client_pin)
```

This still does not fully solve the issue as I can only use a PIN once. After I have used it once, every subsequent call will fail again as you describe. Still researching that.

Comment: Thanks that cleared the errors and basically just dumped me back to the shell prompt. Keeping/reusing a session is the next bit as you say. I'm at a complete loss here as the docs are pretty much non-existent.

Comment: Agreed. Not easy to get this to work. I will keep working on this in my spare time...

Comment: So I did `c.request('/devices')` after and got an error but it also output what appears to be the actual session token. No idea how to re-use it but maybe that will help you.. help me. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Python I would use something like [sanction](http://sanction.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#quickstart) to keep things simple. You should be able to get it to work with the Nest API using code like: (untested, using token flow rather than pin flow)

```
from sanction.client import Client

# instantiating a client to get the auth URI
c = Client(auth_endpoint="https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2",
    client_id=config["nest.client_id"])

# instantiating a client to process OAuth2 response
c = Client(token_endpoint="https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token",
    client_id=config["nest.client_id"],
    client_secret=config["nest.client_secret"])
```

The library is well documented, so you should be able to figure it out from here if something is missing.

Comment: Is there any documentation regarding pin flow (I'm not seeing any)? I don't have a redirect URI.

Comment: To do a pin flow, just omit a Redirect URI in your client and Nest will show the user a PIN at the end of the auth flow. You can use the PIN the same way you would use an access_token from the redirect.

Comment: Do I even need to use client_id/client_secret if I am embedding those in the URL anyways: [https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code](https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code) or am I to assume that Client() does this for me and I should leave off everything after `/access_token`?

Comment: The benefit of using a library like Sanction is you only need to configure the base URLs and library does the the rest (when you call it's API) This is far less error prone than writing out the URLs yourself.

Comment: If that is the case, how do I get the web pin into `c`?